# Interdenominational Christian themed competition on meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

I would like to hear your thought on the possibility of an interdenominational friendly competition for our **meta site**?

[Travel SE](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-competition) has a monthly photo competition. Their rules can be seen [here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6536/april-2020-photo-competition-hotels-and-other-accommodations). Essentially, there's a theme for every month that's related to travel; thus we could improvise it fit our site also.

I am not suggesting a monthly competition, but more along perhaps a friendly Christmas, Easter and  Pentecost competition. It could be monthly or even yearly?

It could be themed as to your preferred family traditions: meals, prayer or whatever?

What say you?

Comment: There could even possibly be a covid-19 themed competition if worded properly. Even Christian need hope during quarantine times and amidst our present social distancing situation.

Comment: Any specific ideas of the kind of competition we could have? Would this be like the Christmas/Easter drives we've had previously?